# Regexp::Common::URI::http - can it find URLs with a dash e.g. my-website.domain.com

Tags: perl, http, uri

I've written a script to attempt to find all the URIs in my config files on an app server. I have noticed, by pure chance, that the Regexp::Common::URI::http module doesn't return the URLs in my config files that contain a dash such as my-website.domain.com.

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

I have also tried using the Regexp::Common::net module to find domains to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://p3rl.org/URI::Find::Schemeless

```
use Regexp::Common qw /URI/;
print "$_\n" for q{f-a-k-e.example.com} =~ m/$RE{URI}{HTTP}/g;
print "$_\n" for q{http://f-a-k-e.example.com} =~ m/$RE{URI}{HTTP}/g;
__END__
http://f-a-k-e.example.com
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I played with URI::Find::Schemeless after I posted this question, and it almost solves my problem - which I have realised is in fact that it didn't find domains in my files unless they have a scheme (http/https/ftp... etc) or were at the start of the line e.g. blah=example-site.domain.com would not be found